# Question up-vote is not crediting 5 points for documentation link

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

For the questions, which have been up-voted with a documentation links, I am getting a reputation of 15 points instead of 10 points (only once). Further up-votes resulting into credit of 10 reputation points.

[What is the difference between Factory and Strategy patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616796/what-is-the-difference-between-factory-and-strategy-patterns/35309666#35309666)

[Does the Bridge Pattern decouples an abstraction from implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079629/the-bridgepattern-decouples-an-abstraction/35079826#35079826)

EDIT :

Two more posts, which does not add points for documentation even though documentation link is embedded in answer.

[How should I have explained the difference between an Interface and an Abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777989/how-should-i-have-explained-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-an-abstract/34978606#34978606)

[Bridge- vs Strategy-Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38814624/bridge-vs-strategy-pattern/38847815#38847815)

I am just looking to understand how things work with respect to adding documentation link in answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you contributed to a documentation example, which is linked in an answer, and the answer gets upvoted, you get some reputation.
You also get the normal "Answer upvoted" reputation.

In your [reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4999394/ravindra-babu?tab=reputation), this can be seen, as well:

[image]

Comment: Does it happen only once? My second example is not resulting 15 reputation for every up vote.  And other thing, documentation link vote score remain same and not incremented with answer up vote.

Comment: The upvotes don't carry over to the documented example. I'm not quite sure where the limits are, though.